# How can I change div inner HTML font size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` element. In this `<div>` there is a `<table>` and `<span>` elements. And the `<span>` does not have a html id attribute.

I want to change font-size in the `<span>`. Can I do it with javascript or jQuery?

I try change class and directly give property with CSS, but they are not working.

How can I change font size?

my `<div class="xxx">`

and in the style

```
 .xxx  {
background-image:url('../k_g.png');
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 0%;
font-size:40px;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code here of what you tried.

Comment: I edit my question. I want to change my div class when I  change it I want to change font size. but it does not work

Comment: Setup fiddle, there is not enough data for proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you span is not a direct child of the div with the class you could do

```
 .xxx span {
     font-size: 40px;
 }
```

However this will affect all spans inside the div and can have unforeseen consequences in the future.

Comment: I edit my question , when I do your solution , the span's background image change , so I do not want this. I want to change only font size

Comment: Did you change your code from .xxx { to .xxx span {? Instead of that just add my css after your existing css.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the below CSS,

```
.xxx > span  {
    font-size:40px;
}
```

Comment: I edit my question , when I do your solution , the span's background image change , so I do not want this. I want to change only font size

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".xxx").css("font-size", "200%");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("div.xxx").children("span").css( "font-size", "30px" );
```

Comment: I do not have span id because span does not have id. I cant give id to span because it is built by different tool.

Comment: This will change the font size of all span tags inside the div.xxx

Answer (score 1):

The first I wonder if this div with .xxx class was create before you call your script or not? If it's ok so just run this script in document.ready function in jQuery:

```
$(".xxx").css({font-size:"30px"});
or jQuery.noConflict();jQuery(".xxx").css({font-size:"30px"});
```

instead of you run some libraries using the same $ for that script.